# Forest plot (ggplot2) and order of variables

Tags: r

I have a data.frame (d) that looks like this:

> ```
> x     y     ylo    yhi 
> A   0.21    0.01   0.41
> D   0.11   -0.09   0.31  
> M   0.13   -0.07   0.33 
> N   0.14   -0.06   0.34
> F   0.17   -0.03   0.37
> ```

I plotted a forest plot using the following code I found on the web:

> ```
> credplot.gg <- function(d){
> require(ggplot2)
> p <- ggplot(d, aes(x=x, y=y, ymin=ylo, ymax=yhi))+geom_pointrange()+
>        coord_flip() + geom_hline(aes(x=0), lty=2)+ xlab('Variable')
> return(p)
> ```
>
> }
>
> credplot.gg(d)

It returns to me the forest plot I need except the fact that the order of my d$x column is changed. Is it possible to plot the forest plot maintaining the order of the elements in the column d$x?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.  Please see [this blog post](http://trinkerrstuff.wordpress.com/2012/10/15/how-do-i-re-arrange-ordering-a-plot/) as this is a factor releveling problem:

Here is how to do it:

```
d$x <- factor(d$x, levels=rev(d$x))
credplot.gg(d)
```